# In the embedded report, there is report.print() API but I want to save the current report view as image, is there a way for this?

Tags: powerbi, react-tsx

I want to export the current report embedded view as image. Report exported as image.

In the embedded report, there is "report.print()" API but I want to save the current report view as image, is there a way for this? please help.